# What is the logic beyond cube collisions?

Tags: physics

I am trying to simulate a colliding of two cubes , I actually tried and read a lot for many days but i did not get the idea beyond it,I know how to detect when they collide.

Maybe my question is divided for many aspects, How to detect rotation and movement of these cubes after colliding , What is status of two cubes would be ?

Sorry if was not clear or dumb, I would thankful if you could help

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for strategies for [tag:collision-resolution], where you modify the motion of the two colliding objects to simulate their physical impact on one another, commonly implemented by applying impulses along the contact manifold. Have you reviewed existing guides and tutorials about building this portion of a physics system?

Comment: No i have not reviewed it , Actually i am so confused about what strategy shall i use ,Many thanks i will see your given link